# How to share login information for two sites with different domains?

Tags: angular, wordpress, authentication, local-storage, cross-domain

I have 2 sites with different domain. Let's call it site A and site B. You can log in to site A and the user information was stored in localStorage.
What I'm trying to achieve is, if you're already logged in in site A, site B will try to access the login information from site A (mainly just the user name) from the same session so you can tell that you're already logged in at site A.

I've tried saving IP and user agent in site A's server, so when someone access site B, it will try to find a match using IP and user agent, but it's not working because someone with the same public address and user agent could falsely informed that they already logged in while in fact they're not.

Is there any different approach that I can try?

I created site A using Angular and site B using Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds suspiciously like you might want to see about using tokens? Something simple like [JWTs](https://jwt.io)?

This would provide a better, signed mechanism to record login (user) information for site B to read about site A. Site B would be able to check and confirm that site A was the issuer and that it's valid, which seems to be your concern (as well it should be).

Edit: Seems to be a [couple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-storage) of [packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-domain-storage) to hook up storage across domains. Not used them so can't comment on them really, but it essentially looks like what you want, I think?

Seems as though once logged in to site A, you can store... something, some flag, marker, or username I guess for your use case. Site B can then read that - or fail to read anything in the cases that users are, in fact, *not* logged in.

Obvious warning: handling logged out users (time-based inactivity as well as clicking a logout button).

Comment: care to elaborate? there's no login mechanism for site B, so I don't know if token really the case here. what I'm trying to achieve is just that site B need to know if in the same browser someone already logged in at site A or not. site B is just a regular landing page